# visualizing a variable by clusters in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(1680) # for reproducibility
df <- data.frame(particle=rnorm(300,rep(1:3,100),1), cluster = rep(1:3,100))
```

I am hoping to visualize particle variable by its cluster. There would be a axis line, and on top of that will be the three clusters of particles. The min and max would be the min of max values of the particles in the cluster, and the wide would be the density of the particles in the cluster at that point. I draw it as an example below: (Sorry about the horrible looking drawing though). I am wondering whether it is possible to achieve this in R with ggplot

[image]

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(cluster = factor(cluster)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = cluster, y = particle, color = cluster)) + geom_point()`

Comment: That just seems like a `geom_jitter` type of plot colored by cluster, no?

Comment: @akrun Great idea!

Comment: @camille Yes, you are right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `geom_violin`

```
df %>%
    mutate(cluster = as.factor(cluster)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cluster, y = particle, fill = cluster)) +
    geom_violin() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]